# Is it possible to add a class for an element that is added by a third-party script

Tags: javascript

A third-party js script is installed on the site, which adds a form to html. Iframe is not used.

I want to add a new class for an element that is generated by a third-party script, but nothing happens.
Please help me understand why.

```
var elem = document.querySelector('.CustomAccountField_689153');
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  elem.classList.add('dropdown');
});
```

Comment: "_nothing happens_" is very rare, have you checked the console for error messages?

Comment: Can you confirm if the third-party element allows this?

Comment: Yes, there is an error in the console
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')`

Comment: Your script doesn't find an element with class `CustomAccountField_689153`. The classname looks dynamic, you could try to use a specific [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) instead of the class selector (like `'[class^="CustomAccountField"]`).

Comment: the element is generated and present in the html and the class of that element has a constant id `<div class="field text CustomAccountField_689153">...`

Comment: Then the timing is off, make sure you're attaching the load listener after the third-party script does it, but before the event fires. And put the DOM query also inside the load listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it takes some time for the library to render the html elements. (There are some reasons for that like getting data from backend, etc).

You can fix it with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) or [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval).

Here is a sample code of setInterval:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  var interval = setInterval(() => {
    var elem = document.querySelector('.CustomAccountField_689153');
    if(elem) {
      elem.classList.add('dropdown');
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 200);
});
```

Using MutationObserver:

```js
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, mutationInstance) {
    var elem = document.querySelector('.CustomAccountField_689153');
    if (elem) {
        elem.classList.add('dropdown');
        mutationInstance.disconnect();
    }
});

observer.observe(document, {
    childList: true,
    subtree:   true
});
```

You can also use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) if you know how long does it take to load the element:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  /* The time requires to load the element in ms */
  const time = 1000;

  setTimeout(() => {
    var elem = document.querySelector('.CustomAccountField_689153');
    elem.classList.add('dropdown');
  }, time);
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. I also added a sample code for MutationObserver.

Comment: I tried for MutationObserver
Got an error: ncaught TypeError: observer.Observe is not a function

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. It's "observe" not "Observe". (The first letter is not capital). I updated the code.

Comment: which solution worked? @oleksiyvasilik

Answer (score 1):

Select the element after the window loads

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  var elem = document.querySelector('.CustomAccountField_689153');
  elem.classList.add('dropdown');
});

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
setTimeout(()=>{
var elem = document.querySelector('.CustomAccountField_689153');
  elem.classList.add('dropdown');
})
},1000)
  ;
```

Comment: Not working, error status is the same `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')`

Comment: Your CustomAccountField_689153 is not present at the time when code runs. if you know how much time it will take then u can use second method

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I tried setTimeout earlier and it didn't work